# Access multidimensional Array via String in groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to access a JSON HasMap via String like `data['dimension1']['dimension2']` but i want to do that dynamically like `data[myAccessor]`.

### Code

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

dataContent = '''
{
  "Test": {
    "Info": "Hello"
  }
}
'''

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurperClassic()
data = jsonSlurper.parseText(dataContent)

println data['Test']['Info']  // Prints 'Hello'

accessor = "'Test']['Info'"
println data[accessor]  // Prints 'null'

'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can't just execute complex text as code like that  (or , I can't decide)

The best you can do is to have `accessor` be something splittable like

```
accessor = 'Test->Info'
```

And then you can split this and "*walk*" down the input structure to get the result you're after like so:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

dataContent = '''
{
  "Test": {
    "Info": "Hello"
  }
}
'''

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurperClassic()
data = jsonSlurper.parseText(dataContent)

accessor = "Test->Info"

println accessor.split('->').inject(data) { currentData, accessorPart ->
    currentData?.getAt(accessorPart)
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Tim !

Comment: Can I also use this Technique to change the `Hello` Value to some other Value ?

Comment: @DirkSchiller Yes.  You can reduce along the path except the last element (e.g. using `.dropRight(1)`) and then put your value with the last element on the resulting map (if there is one)

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage Groovy's [Eval](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.11/html/gapi/groovy/util/Eval.html) and represent the *accessor* with [property notation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_map_property_notation) to have something closer to your intent:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

dataContent = '''
{
  "Test": {
    "Info": "Hello"
  }
}
'''

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurperClassic()
data = jsonSlurper.parseText(dataContent)

println data.'Test'.'Info' // prints 'Hello'
accessor = "'Test'.'Info'"

Eval.x(data, "println x.${accessor}") // prints 'Hello'
```

Comment: Thank you Jalopaba!

Comment: One note on eval is to be wary of user input. Someone sending in `"X; System.exit(1)"` could halt the jvm